# Filter value in Datatable is not persist when clicking on button

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am facing a problem to preserve the state of the search value in data Table. I have data table which fetching the details data. Now there is a search field for each and every column. When I write some thing on the search field matching value for that particular page being populated. Now In my application If I click against each row a close button will appear with  details value. If i click on the close button the page is getting closed but the main page lost the filter value . I want to preserve the search value after closing the child page.

Please help me out as I am stuck in the issue. Thanks in advance.

function called on click of close button::

```
$('#closeDivButton').on('click',function(){
                            $('#detailsPage').hide();
                           exampletable.$('#action').show();
}
```

In the jsp page:

saving the state of datatable by doing the following things::

```
.DataTable(
                                                            {
                                                                //"responsive" : true,
                                                                //"bStateSave": false,
                                                                "destroy" : true,
                                                                "autoWidth" : false,
                                                                "stateSave" : true,
                                                                "ajax" : {
}

$('#example tfoot td')
                                                    .each(
                                                            function() {
                                                                var title = $(
                                                                        this)
                                                                        .text();
                                                                //alert('search4:'+title);
                                                                $(this)
                                                                        .html(
                                                                                '<input id="searchbutton" type="text" size="10" placeholder="Search '+title+'" /><img src="'+contextPath+'/img/clear.png" id="clearsearch" title="Clear" width="15px;" height="15px;"/>');
                                                                //$(this).html( '<div class="input-placeholder"><input id="searchbutton" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 form-control" type="text" size="10" placeholder="Search" /><span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span></div>' );
                                                            });
                                            // Restore state
                                            var state = exampletable.state.loaded();
                                            //alert('state5:'+state);
                                            if ( state ) {
                                                exampletable.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
                                                  var colSearch = state.columns[colIdx].search;

                                                  if ( colSearch.search ) {
                                                    $( 'input', exampletable.column( colIdx ).footer() ).val( colSearch.search );
                                                  }
                                                } );

                                                exampletable.draw();
                                              }
```

It is working when the page got refreshed but not working when click on the close button to hide details information.

Comment: can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: I have edited and add sample code.